# Displaying a progress indicator during UIActivityItemProvider activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I've got a `UIActivityViewController` which allows the user to share an image they've created to one of several activity types (facebook, twitter, save to camera roll, print, etc.).

Since I want the image to be saved/sent at different quality levels depending on the activity (high-resolution to print, low-res for twitter), I'm using a custom `UIActivityItemProvider` to (duh) provide the image.

Rendering the hi-res version takes some time, so I want to display an activity indicator while it's doing its thing.  The apple docs make reference to doing just that, actually.

But I can't seem to figure out the "right" places to put the hooks for displaying my progress indicator... where should they go?

**UPDATE:**
Tried the following in the `- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType` method:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startSpinnerWithMessage:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:YES];

self.shareImage = [self.delegate imageForActivityOfType:activityType]; // code that actually generates the image; takes a while.

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(endSpinner) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

...does not do the job.  When I tap the activity button, the UI freezes while the image is generated, and then when it finishes, I see the spinner for a split second and then it disappears.

I think the positioning of the endSpinner call makes sense... however, it seems that the startSpinner call needs to go somewhere else.  No idea what to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, turns out I was just going about this wrong...

I was putting my grab-the-image-from-the-delegate code in the `- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType` method from the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.  Turns out that method is fired on the main thread.

Instead, I put the same code in the `UIActivityItemProvider`'s `- (id) item` method, and it works like a charm.